Автоматически переносить изменения из master-ветки в stage-ветку
Требуется помощь в следующем вопросе:
В проекте, помимо рабочих веток разработчиков, существуют ветки master и stage
После принятия MR и изменений в master-ветке (после MR, или в ходе хотфиксов) требуется автоматически копировать изменения в stage-ветку. Обе ветки в проекте protected.
Происходит всё в GitLab.
Прошу подсказать, как можно выполнить данные операции, возможно, требуется джобу в pipeline дописать или можно в настройках проекта как-то настроить?

Здесь ACCESS_TOKEN - токен проекта с правами на запись в репозиторий, а остальные переменные - предопределены в GitLab:
synchro_master_stage:
  stage: sync
  script:
    - git config --global user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
    - git config --global user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
    - git push origin -ff  --progress http://${GITLAB_USER_LOGIN}:${ACCESS_TOKEN}@<Gitlab`s URL>/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git HEAD:stage
  when:
    - master

